# Python EXE to request sudo access

Tags: python-3.x, windows, macos, sudo, scapy

I am working on a script to monitor my outgoing website connections. As an example, if I connect to reddit, I'd like the IP address of Reddit to be logged.

I have this functionality down just fine, but in the future, I'd like someone else to be able to run my Python code as an EXE file. However, my script currently requires you to run as Sudo since it is sniffing the IP addresses.

I'd like non-technical users to be able to use my app by simply clicking an EXE or entering their password if prompted. In order for it to provide maximum benefit for the end user, they would need the ability for it to run on computer start-up rather than having to activate it manually.

How can you run a Python EXE for this purpose without needing the user to utilize the command line? (I know how to make an EXE, but I mean not needing to use sudo)

OS would be mac and windows.

Comment: Normally in Windows this would be split into two processes: a privileged process in session 0 (the non-interactive services session) that hosts a service, and a client process in an interactive session. The installer requests admin access to install the service, with the normal UAC consent prompt. Standard users can be granted the right to start and stop the service, in which case the client application can start the service, or it can be set to start automatically at boot.

Comment: The equivalent in Unix is a daemon process that hosts a service, but the details vary.

Comment: Thank you Eryk! In that case, with Windows, if I simply convert the file to an EXE will it automatically go through that process upon running? Or will I need to add some special code to make that functionality happen?

Comment: You have your work cut out for you. The PyWin32 package has support for the services API. It also provides `ShellExecuteEx` if you need to respawn with admin access to install and configure the service. The installer, service, and client aspects can all be implemented by a single executable if desired. But you have to write code for all of this. It's not a one-click compile option, unless you find a convenient framework that masks all of the gory details.

Comment: Thank you, that's very helpful. It's time to get to work then :)